# how to handle swipe action for same direction in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

As you see in the image above, 
i'm using recycler view as horizontal in a root and nested vertical recyclerView with swipe menu (reference : https://github.com/TUBB/SwipeMenu )
and this can only swipe for horizontal recycler View, but i want to handle swipe action for swipe menu as well.
please help me thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can swipe any view in any direction, you just need to set the right `TouchListener` and handle touch events in the way you want.

For example the following library use swipe inside `RecyclerView` in all direction:
https://github.com/chthai64/SwipeRevealLayout